# Selecting A Series Of Text Boxes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a series(10) of selectable TextBoxes. I need to be able to click on one of them and select all the text boxes on which the mouse is moved until the click is released.

I used the following code but I am unable to hit the MouseMove on the other TextBoxes. It always hits the TextBox on which the Click was made.

```
class SelectableTextBox: TextBox
{
    public Boolean IsSelected { get; protected set; }

    public void select(Boolean value)
    {
        this.IsSelected = value;
        if (value)
        {
            this.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Aqua;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White;
        }
    }
}

private void onPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    SelectableTextBox textBox = (SelectableTextBox)sender;

    this.SelectionStartedRight = !textBox.IsSelected;
    textBox.select(!textBox.IsSelected);
}

private void onPreviewMouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    SelectableTextBox textBox = (SelectableTextBox)sender;

    if (this.SelectionStartedRight)
    {
        textBox.select(true);
    }
}

private void onPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    SelectableTextBox textBox = (SelectableTextBox)sender;

    this.SelectionStartedRight = false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `MouseEnter` event instead of `MouseMove`.  Attach `MouseEnter` to your selectable textboxes.  That would ensure that only they trigger the desired event handler and its code.

If you decide to stay with the global handler, be careful when you convert `sender` to a specific control type.  You need to account for those times when it's not the "expected" control:

```
SelectableTextBox textBox = sender as SelectableTextBox;

if (textBox != null)
{
    // The rest of the code here...
}
```

`select` is a `Linq` keyword, so you might want to rename that method to avoid any conflicts down the road.  While I don't think it'd be causing any issues, I would change it.

You don't have to follow this convention, but in `C#` its customary to use an uppercase for the first letter of a method. Also note that the default access modifier for a class is `internal`... just want to make sure you're aware of that, as you continue your development.

Your last method, `onPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(...)` has the following code in it:

```
SelectableTextBox textBox = (SelectableTextBox)sender;
```

Not only is it unsafe, as I've described above, but it also does absolutely nothing.

Lastly... and this is just me, I would probably move the code that handles changing the state of a selectable textbox (selected or not selected) into its class, since it belongs there.  Why should anything else be in charge of how it handles its state.  Keep things where they belong and you'll have a much easier time testing, debugging and maintaining your code.  Don't fall into the "I'll refactor it later" trap... it'll rarely happen.

Here's my crude example. I let the class handle its `MouseEnter` event and simply check if the `Mouse.LeftButton` is down at that time.  You would have to expand on it, but it should be a solid start:

**Made some edits per OP's requests in the comments.**

**Preview:**

[image]

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="SelectableTextBoxes.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SelectableTextBoxes"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <local:SelectableTextBox Height="20" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <local:SelectableTextBox Height="20" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <local:SelectableTextBox Height="20" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <local:SelectableTextBox Height="20" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
        <local:SelectableTextBox Height="20" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**C# (Pardon me for putting the `SelectableTextBox` into the same file...):**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace SelectableTextBoxes
{
    // Move this class into its own file (it's here for prototyping).
    public class SelectableTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private bool _isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set
            {
                if (_isSelected != value)
                {
                    _isSelected = value;
                    // If the value changes, sets new color.
                    SetSelectionColor();
                }
            }
        }

        public SelectableTextBox()
        {
            // For handling an initial click if it happens in the textbox.
            PreviewMouseDown += SelectableTextBox_PreviewMouseDown;
            // For handling selection when mouse enters the textbox
            // and left mouse button is down.
            MouseEnter += SelectableTextBox_MouseEnter;    
            // To handle mouse capture (release it).     
            GotMouseCapture += SelectableTextBox_GotMouseCapture;
        }

        // Handles the mouse down event within the textbox.
        void SelectableTextBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsSelected)
            {
                IsSelected = true;
            }

            // If one of the Shift keys is down, return, since
            // we don't want to deselect others.
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
            {
                return;
            }

            // This part makes a poor assumption that the parent is
            // always going to be a Panel... expand on this code to
            // cover other types that may contain more than one element.
            var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this) as Panel;

            if (parent != null)
            {
                foreach (var child in parent.Children)
                {
                    // If a child is not of a correct type, it'll be null.
                    var tbx = child as SelectableTextBox;
                    // This is where we check to see if it's null or this instance.
                    if (tbx != null && tbx != this)
                    {
                        tbx.IsSelected = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // When textbox receives focus, this event fires... we need to release
        // the mouse to continue selection.
        void SelectableTextBox_GotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }

        // Sets selection state to true if the left mouse button is 
        // down while entering.
        void SelectableTextBox_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                IsSelected = true;
            }
        }

        // Sets the background color based on selection state.
        private void SetSelectionColor()
        {
            if (IsSelected)
            {
                Background = Brushes.LightCyan;
            }
            else
            {
                Background = Brushes.White;
            }
        }
    }

    // Window code... should be on its own, but I placed the two
    // classes together while prototyping.
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for the quick response. This worked exactly as you explained. The only situation it does not work is when I click on one of the TextBoxes and start moving the Mouse over the other. If I can get this to work the user will be able to click anywhere and move over the TextBoxes.

Comment: @JourneyMan Check the edit.  I added a `GotMouseCapture` event handler that should take care of that issue.

Comment: I am sorry for the naive question but isn't clicking on the textbox the same as clicking within? The requirements were: a) Clicking on the text box should select the textbox and deselect others. b) clicking on the textbox and moving over others should select the initial textbox and the others on which it hovers on.

Comment: BTW, all the other suggestions you provided we very valuable and am planning to follow them.

Comment: @JourneyMan Glad that worked.  It obviously won't handle unselecting other textboxes, so some external code would probably be needed, unless you want to dive into dependency property realm.

Comment: @JourneyMan I added some additional code that takes care of deselecting others, without having external code worry about it.  Basically, it looks for all the other children of the type `SelectableTextBox` in the parent if its a `Panel`.  You should add additional code to check for other types of controls, besides `Panel`, but that should be a good start.

Comment: @JourneyMan Also added code that allows you to select multiple text boxes by Shift+Clicking on them (see the code in the `SelectableTextBox_PreviewMouseDown(...)` method.